# Yet another .htaccess question

Tags: .htaccess, get, wamp

I have a .htaccess file on a WAMP server.  The .htaccess Rewrites work fine...for some easy url rewrites, but I can't get it working on a simple test.

My .htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^Homepage/$ index.php
RewriteRule ^Test/(.*)/$ test.php?a=$1
```

On my test.php I'm dumping out $_GET.

My Homepage works fine, i.e. http://www.mysite.com/Homepage/ is redirecting just fine.  But my Test page is only partially working in that it goes to the test.php but nothing is getting dumped from my $_GET dump - it's just an empty array.

Ideally I need to do this for multiple folders, e.g.

```
RewriteRule ^Test/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/$ test.php?a=$1&b=$2&c=$3
```

...but I can't even get my simple test working.

BTW - this same .htaccess works perfectly in my Linux environment (dev server).  I now need to move this to a production Windows box and it's simply not working.

If it helps this .htaccess file is sitting in a subfolder e.g. C:\wamp\www\mywebsite\.htaccess

What am I doing wrong?  Any ideas?  Thanks in advance.

UPDATE:

Turned on Rewrite Log (substitude real website name with mywebsite) and http://www.mywebsite.com/Test/ABC/ returns this:

```
217.42.222.22 - - [31/Mar/2011:23:08:16 +0100] [www.mywebsite.com/sid#65f3f0][rid#1a13a68/subreq] (1) [perdir C:/wamp/www/mywebsite.com/] pass through C:/wamp/www/mywebsite.com/test.php
217.42.222.22 - - [31/Mar/2011:23:08:16 +0100] [www.mywebsite.com/sid#65f3f0][rid#1a2ea88/initial] (1) [perdir C:/wamp/www/mywebsite.com/] pass through C:/wamp/www/mywebsite.com/test.php
217.42.222.22 - - [31/Mar/2011:23:08:16 +0100] [www.mywebsite.com/sid#65f3f0][rid#1a24af0/subreq] (1) [perdir C:/wamp/www/mywebsite.com/] pass through C:/wamp/www/mywebsite.com/ABC
```

I'm still none the wiser ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Two suggestions:

1. post the url that you're using for the Test page.
2. turn on the rewrite log and see what it says.  Just be sure to turn it off again later!

Answer (score 0):

Have your rewrite rule like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^Homepage/$ /index.php [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^Test/(.*)/$ /test.php?a=$1 [R=301,L]
```

target of rewrite rules should start with a /

Comment: @CWA: I made a minor modification by adding `[R=301,L]` in above rules. I also have `xampp` installed on Windows XP and have tested above rules there they are ALL working fine there. In my browser when I entered this URL `http://localhost/Test/foo/` it got redirected to `http://localhost/test.php?a=foo`